# Regex to match the pattern [-][number][number]

Tags: c#, regex

hi i need to match the following string in c#

for example

-34

-67

-23

-46

-00

i would loop over the string and check each char but thats messy and i have no idea about regex so was hoping for some help.

thanks

Comment: Hi Tom, not an answer to your question but whenever i have a RegEx query i have a look on this site as most of the time there is a regex string ready to use.  http://www.regexlib.com/

Comment: Also i would like to add a great tool RegExr which is very helpfull in creating reg expressions.  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-(\d\d)` is the pattern

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"-(\d\d)");
var matches = rx.Matches(str);
foreach (var match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 4):

The following regex should work

```
@"-\d\d"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think -\d\d should be able to do it